# Is there a way to have a custom, non-consecutive number range for an Excel spin button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spin button that needs to start at 1000, then go up (by increments of 1) to 1099. However, instead of going to 1100 after 1099, I need the next number to be 2000 (then process repeats of going to 2099). By only inputting a SpinButton1.Min and Max, the button circles through many numbers that I do not need.

Is there a VBA formula that will let me input a custom number range for the spin putting. Specifically, the range would be [1000-1099] [2000-2099].

Thanks!

Comment: And you need them in an array? What have you tried?

Comment: What's the function of this button, and where is it located - on a form or on a worksheet?  It would be better to give the user a second control to pick the range of numbers (1000's, 2000's,etc) and then just have the spin button go from 0-99 - you can use a formula to get the final number from the two controls.

Comment: I thought of having a second control to pick the first digit, but as the first digit will soon go from 1 to 9, I thought this would be a bit much. But yes, for future reference I think having two controls would be beneficial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the following macro to your spin button:

```
Sub SB()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rng = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7") '<-- input the Cell and worksheet
                                                   'your spin Button is assigned to here
i = rng.Value

If i < 1000 Then
    i = 1000
ElseIf i > 1099 And i < 1550 Then
    i = 2000
ElseIf i < 2000 And i >= 1550 Then
    i = 1099
ElseIf i > 2099 Then
    i = 2099
End If

rng.Value = i
End Sub
```

It will just prevent the cell from taking any other values than the ones in your desired interval, and all inputs from 1100 to 1549 will jump to 2000 while the inputs from 1550 to 1999 will jump to 1000.